# Calculating sample size for one 5-point likert item

Tags: sample-size, ordinal-data, sample, likert

I am trying to calculate the optimal sample size for a hypothetical experiment with the following:

Treatment condition (n TBD)
Control condition (n TBD)

My dependent variable is an 'intent score' derived from one 5-point Likert item: 
1 = not at all
2 = slightly
3 = somewhat
4 = very
5 = extremely

**H₁** Median score of future intentions |T| > Median score of future intentions |C|

**H₀** Median score of future intentions |C|  ≤  Median score of future intentions |T|

Most sample size calculations require a mean, which is not possible with ordinal data as far as I'm aware.

Any advice to calculate a sample size here?

Comment: Before you can compute power you need to sort out a few things first. When you say [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) is it an actual scale or just one Likert item? What are your null and alternative? What test are you planning to do?

Comment: I have added more details of my hypotheses into the original post. It's a super simple hypothetical experiment where the dependent variable is the score of one question/Likert item

Comment: Is your actual interest specifically on the median or did you just say "median" because that's something you know goes with ordinal responses? [I ask because it affects the advice. For example, specifying median would generally exclude using (say) a Mann-Whitney.]

Comment: I care about whether there is a difference in the average scores between two groups (e.g. is 'intent' overall higher for one group than the other?)My prior research suggests the 'median' is the best way to assess this as the data is ordinal.

Comment: The two statements "difference in the average" and "is intent overall higher for one group than another" are not normally equivalent statements. I'd usaally interpret "overall higher" to be either a statement about $P(X>Y)>\frac12$ (X is usually larger than Y), or even about stochastic dominance (ordering of cdfs, say $P(X>t)>P(Y>t)$ for all $t$, a much stricter kind of "greater than"). The first (which is what Mann-Whitney actually tests) needn't go in the same direction as differences in means or in medians (or those two things might go in different directions themselves),  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... but the second thing should have all of them in the same direction. If your original interest was on medians I might suggest a permutation test based on the median but if it's more like one is more often larger I might have suggested a Mann-Whitney,  ... People tend to have a very unclear attitude about which possible "greater than" hypothesis they're interested in; but it matters -- different ones may lead to opposite conclusions!

Comment: Exactly, I care about if "more often larger than the other "(my alternate hypothesis could be Future intentions (T) >  future intentions (C).  I wonder if I'm best treating likert-item data as continuous rather than ordinal for the purposes of calculating a sample size... :/

Comment: Saying that it's continuous won't affect which test you do the power calculation on; just because it's continuous doesn't make it normal with constant variance, so you'd still presumably be using the Mann-Whitney for your "one more often larger than the other" style of alternative (that's exactly what MW does!). I think I am now in a position to construct an answer, at least.